# Can seaborn's countplot() plot NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I was given a huge file with some data we had to classify by hand, so, using Excel we placed a column that should be filled with "Y" or "N" (mainly, there are other values), if the row fits certain criteria.

So, I'm writing a report on how percentage of work we've done, and I want to include some charts.

Using Panda's plot, this statement would do the work:

```
sw.industrial.value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

With seaborn I could use:

```
sns.countplot(data=sw, x='industrial')
```

It gives me a nice chart, but not the nans. Is there a way to tell seaborn to use the nans as Panda do?

Comment: Like a count of the NaNs? Just assign a value to NaN and then plot it, and change the xtick to "Missing" or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fill the missing values with  something and then use xticks to set the axis markers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Industrial" : ["Y", "N", "Y", "N", NA, NA, NA, "N", "N", "N", "Y"]})

df["Industrial"] = df['Industrial'].fillna('M')
sns.countplot(data=df, x='Industrial')
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), ("Yes", "No","Missing"))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In the end, that's what I did, but I was looking for an "auto" way to do it